# A better way to randomly select a key and value pair from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

As far as I know `array_rand()` can only grab a radnom array from an array like this:

```
$array = array( 'apple', 'orange', 'banana' );
$two_random_items = array_rand( $array , 2 ); // outputs i.e. orange and banana
```

But how can I grab 2 random items but with the key value array? Like this?

```
$array = array( '0' => 'apple', '1' => 'orange', '2' => 'banana' );
$rand_keys = array_rand($array, 2);
$rand_values = array();
foreach ($rand_keys as $key) {
    $rand_values[] .= $array[$key];
}
```

That's probably not the right way and it's a lot of code.

I have a big array this is just an example and I need to grab 1000+ or more items randomly from the parent array and put them in a new array, keys can be reset, this is not important. The value part has to stay the same, of course.

Is there a better way how to achieve this?

Comment: @KA_lin can you post a more clear answer if possible, tahnks

Comment: Sorry, haven`t read until the end.

Comment: use rand from database, or only in memory need ?

Comment: @KA_lin For large arrays, that's a terrible idea. Lot's of wasted performance doing the sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just shuffle and slice 2:

```
shuffle($array);
$rand_values = array_slice($array, 0, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, this line: `$rand_values[] .= $array[$key];` is wrong. The `.=` operator is to join strings, to add a value to the end of the array, you just need `$rand_values[] = $array[$key];`.

If you don't care about the keys, just use `array_values` function to "dump" the keys.

```
$array = array('a' => 'orange', 'c' => 'banana', 'b' => 'peach');
$two_random_items = array_rand(array_values($array) , 2 );
```

[array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) will strip down the keys, and will return an array with the values (the keys will become 0, 1, 2...)